# Prioritization of features in Boards

Tags: azure-devops

The backlog priority in boards seems to be reprioritize continuously. This is uncomfortable as a productowner since I'm not the one changing. My conclusion is that team members with contributor access reorders in the kanbanboard. The card reorder setting is set to following the backlog priority.

My ask for help is how to deny contributors to prioritize features? New features could be put in the bottom

Comment: Hi ,Tiger Are the answer below helpful?If you have any question about this case,please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, unless you completely remove write permissions from those accounts.

However, you can create an E-Mail notification on Backlog Priorty change:
[image]

Please note that a reorder of the backlog happens in an unexpected way when you rearrange child Product Backlog Items / User Storys inside the Epic or Feature Backlog.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, you could try the solution below.

For >>how to deny contributors to prioritize features.

Firstly, you could edit priority of feature by PCA to click **Organization Settings** >> **Process** >> **Feature**. The screenshot of my step is as follows.

[image]

Then, click **Priority** >> … >> **Edit**. You could open a new page where you could set the default value of priority, which can deny contributors to prioritize features.

**Please note that it can only be edited for inherited process.**

Here is my screenshot.

[image]

For >>new features could be put in the bottom.
When add new features, you could select **Add to bottom**. 
Here is my screenshot.
[image]